# Linux Mint 15: How to change permission of /opt folder

Tags: permissions, linux-mint, software-installation

I'm trying install Pycharm Community 3.0.1. I'm extremely new to Linux and don't really know how to install things without explicit instructions (which for more popular software has just been pasting lines of commands into the terminal), which after searching online I've only found the following instructions:
[Install Pycharm on Linux Mint](http://gbteknotes.blogspot.com/2013/05/install-pycharm-on-linux-mint.html)

However trying to move the extracted folder results in a "Permission Denied" error. How would I change the permissions of /opt so I can move the folder?

Or is there a better way to install things like this? The original file was a .tar.gz folder.

Answer (score 1):

I would use the command `sudo` to copy/move the files to `/opt` rather than change the permissions over there so that other users can write to it, besides the root user. A command such as this would do it:

```
$ sudo mv <unpacked directory> /opt
$ sudo chown -R root.root /opt/<unpacked directory>
```

**NOTE:** This isn't meant as a literal "" it's a placeholder, put the actual name of the directory after you unpacked the Pycham archive.

Answer (score 0):

it's not good to change permissions of any folder inside "/" !

```
u@h:~$ ls -ld /opt
drwxr-xr-x 4 root root 4096 Oct  4 18:58 /opt
```

in order to copy/move from/to such folders which owned by root , you simply run your commands as root !
* how run cmds as root ?
using 'sudo' :

```
sudo command
```

or
login into root user , and do your tasks , exit :

```
sudo -i #will ask  for user password and it will open a session inside /root dir !
su #will ask for root passwor , and it will stay in same dir where you're '~/'
```

[image: screenshot]